# Best performance choice for cookie arrays in PHP and JS?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, cookies

Hi I have a website with hundreds of tv shows and tens of thousands of episodes. I want the user (who didn't log in) to be able to save his favorites shows and to mark the episodes he's watched and save these data using cookies.

So I've already implemented it both in PHP and JS. I just wanted to know what's the best choice when it comes to arrays of cookies.

Now I save the data in a cookie called 'favorites', which is a JSON encoded array which simply contains the IDs of the tv shows.
In the cookie 'watched' there are the IDs of the episodes that the user has marked as watched.

What's the best option for performance and memory? You must keep in mind this is also intended for mobiles so, if the user marks thousand of episodes as watched, I don't want this to slow down everything.

The code below is not real code, it's just to make you understand the differences between the options.

**Option 1**

one cookie called 'watched' which is a JSON encoded array containing the IDs. I would need to check if the array contains that value

```
$_COOKIE['watched'] = array(1,2,3,4,...)
```

With this option, in the tv-show page I would always have to pick the whole array and check if every single episode ID is a value in the array.

**Option 2**

one cookie for each ID, called for example "watched_[ID]". I would just check if it exists or not.

```
exists( $_COOKIE['watched_1'] ) ? watched : !watched
exists( $_COOKIE['watched_2'] ) ? watched : !watched
```

**Option 3**

one cookie called 'watched' which is an associative JSON encoded array containing an array for each tv show, called for example 'watched[show_ID]', and each one of these contain only the IDs of the episodes marked as watched belonging to that show. (so in the tv-show page I first check for 'watched[show_ID]' then I already have all the watched episodes, instead of comparing every single episode ID with the array 'watched' from Option 1

```
$_COOKIE['watched'] = array(
               1 => array(1,2,3),
               2 => array(4,5,6)
)
```

Comment: Note that there are other options possible; e.g. a tracking cookie and server-side storage or using LocalStorage and AJAX. Not saying they are better, but just saying they exist.

Comment: Since the very moment I found out JS can get and set cookies, I've never even considered the idea of using AJAX just to check a cookie. Why would I bother the server when I can avoid that? Anyway I've written down the 3 options that are best in my opinion. Of course I'm open to any other suggestion, but remember that I didn't ask for the best option to handle cookies in my website, I asked for the best way to handle data in cookies arrays.

Comment: The AJAX is then solely used to render your page, it's used to generate dynamic content based on the LocalStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Approach you select will purely depend on the type of users you have, if data size generally is large in your case then you should go with option 3 as associative arrays are a good approach when it comes to large data size as it will be somewhat easy to loop through them and get the results.

If your users data set is fairly small then option 2 is the best approach as we have different cookies for each shows and you could immediately check the corresponding values.

Further I would like you to go through the html5 api to use indexed db as a solution to your problem as it provides client side DB and further it is a persistent database.
Hope this helps

Comment: It helped a lot, thank you very much. Since the user has the possibility to set every show as favorite and every episode as watched, I will choose Option 3.

Answer (score 0):

Something not addressed in the accepted answer is browser cookie limitations (on the client side of things). Option 2 will clearly not work due to the limits on the number of cookies allowed:

```
Browser              Num Cookies    Size Per Cookie    Size Per Domain
-------              -----------    ---------------    ---------------
Chrome 8-25          180            4096 bytes         
FireFox 3.6.13-19    150            4097 characters
IE 8/9/10             50            5117 characters    10234 characters
Safari               600            4093 bytes          4093 bytes
Android 2.1/2.3.4     50            4096 bytes
Safari Mobile 5.1    600            4093 bytes          4093 bytes
```

Some of those numbers may be outdated...[[source]](http://phillihp.com/2013/08/08/test-your-browsers-cookie-limitations/)

However, you will still have to be careful when utilizing options 1 or 3 due to the size limitation per cookie/domain. [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rL92znr3/) shows how big a strigified associative array is when it contains 1000 items with a key length of 7 characters each (it's about 12000 bytes).

If you're intent on storing thousands of items in cookies, you will probably have to write a cookie wrapper library that chunks your data across multiple cookies to avoid the per-cookie size limitations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I had no idea there was a browser limit for cookies. This is quite important, and I could fix it for the 'favorites' tv-shows by setting a limit. I can't set a limit for the watched episode tho, since it would be nonsense... thank you, I'll have to figure out something else then.

Comment: I didn't think about it either until I tried writing a simple performance test for option 2. It only saved 180 of my 10,000 cookies! :)

Comment: Haha yes that's definitely not a good thing. Have you every thought of a solution to bypass this limit? My first thought now is to generate a random ID for the user and save it as a cookie, and store the favorites associated to that ID in the database. So it will be 1 cookie for the user, 1 row of data in my database... how does that sound to you? This way I can also keep track of which shows are more popular.

Comment: Sounds good to me, although I would use some sort of tracking token string as opposed to an actual user id.

Comment: Can you explain it better? And please be clear, I don't speak english that well, I'm already lost at "tracking token" :) Anyway since it's not a proper user ID yes, I can use anything like a random string or stringS to identify him

Comment: You've got it already, sounds like. I was just suggesting to use an ID other than a proper user ID.